# Pandas Dataframe Derive the new calculated columns based on existing input columns (refer the current and previous row without using loop)

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below requirement to derive the new columns as below# Kindly suggest. 
In my actual dataset, have more than 10+ million records and am giving only sample records
For a given P, T & W values we need to derive the new columns D1% & D2% based on existing columns (A1,A2,S1&S2).
1)  Any point of time, if S1 have value A or B we need to hardcode the value D1% as zero
2)  Any point of time, if S2 have value A or B we need to hardcode the value D2% as zero
3)  If S1 is not equal to A or B, we need to calculate the D1% as below:
((Current A1 value – Previous A1 value) / Previous A1 value) * 100

If S2 is not equal to A or B, we need to calculate the D2% as below:
((Current A2 value – Previous A2 value) / Previous A2 value) * 100

Example # For P = 10, T = 1, W=1, D1% is  ‘0’, as S1 Is having value ‘A’.
                   For P = 10, T = 1, W=1, D2% is  ‘0’, as S2 Is having value ‘B’.

```
               For P = 10, T = 1, W=2, A1=11 and S1 Is having value ‘C’.
                D1% = ((11-10)/10) * 100 = 10%

                For P = 10, T = 1, W=2, A2=25 and S2 Is having value ‘C’.
                D2% = ((25-20)/20) * 100 = 25%
```

```
Input DataFrame:
P   T   W   A1  A2  S1  S2
10  1   1   10  20  A   B
10  1   2   11  25  C   C
10  1   3   10  15  D   D
10  1   4   9   10  C   C
10  1   5   8   5   C   C
10  2   1   20  40  B   A
10  2   2   10  10  C   C
10  2   3   15  30  C   C
10  2   4   5   20  D   D
10  2   5   25  10  C   C
```

```
Expected Output DataFrame:

P   T   W   A1  A2  S1  S2  D1% D2%
10  1   1   10  20  A   B   0   0
10  1   2   11  25  C   C   10  25
10  1   3   10  15  D   D   -9.090909091    -40
10  1   4   9   10  C   C   -10 -33.33333333
10  1   5   8   5   C   C   -11.11111111    -50
10  2   1   20  40  B   A   0   0
10  2   2   10  10  C   C   -50 -75
10  2   3   15  30  C   C   50  200
10  2   4   5   20  D   D   -66.66666667    -33.33333333
10  2   5   25  10  C   C   400 -50
```

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: I have tried with for loop on groups based on P, T and W. comparing current and previous records and not able to get the complete correct output and also it might not work with large dataset due to memory issue.looking for any other solution

Comment: so if  S1 and S2 both has either A or B? like C , B then too you want 0 and 0? or is it that both A and b has to be present ?

Comment: There is no dependency on S1 and S2.                                D1 derived based on S1 using the A1 value.                      D2 derived based on S2 using the A2 value.                      Hope am not confusing here. Please advise

Comment: @ramk what i meant is when you check for A or B , I hope you meant either A or B is present in any of the columns in S1 and S2 , if so , my answer below should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i understand you can [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) the 2 columns S1 and S2 and check if [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html) of the value in the same index `level=0` is A or B, then using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) , where the condition matches , assign 0 else assign the [`pct_change`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html) which is same as the calculation you showed on columns A1 and A2

```
cond = df[['S1','S2']].stack().isin(['A','B']).any(level=0)
arr = np.where(cond[:,None], np.zeros(len(df))[:,None],
                df[['A1','A2']].pct_change().mul(100).round(2))
df[['D1%','D2%']] = pd.DataFrame(arr)
```

---

```
print(df)

    P  T  W  A1  A2 S1 S2     D1%     D2%
0  10  1  1  10  20  A  B    0.00    0.00
1  10  1  2  11  25  C  C   10.00   25.00
2  10  1  3  10  15  D  D   -9.09  -40.00
3  10  1  4   9  10  C  C  -10.00  -33.33
4  10  1  5   8   5  C  C  -11.11  -50.00
5  10  2  1  20  40  B  A    0.00    0.00
6  10  2  2  10  10  C  C  -50.00  -75.00
7  10  2  3  15  30  C  C   50.00  200.00
8  10  2  4   5  20  D  D  -66.67  -33.33
9  10  2  5  25  10  C  C  400.00  -50.00
```